# Force vim to quit from editing list of files

Tags: bash, shell, vim, for-loop, vi

To make common modifications, I generally edit all files in a sub-directory using:

```
for i in `ls`; do vim $i; done
```

Now, I want to exit from VIM in between to command prompt, but VIM doesn't allows me. After `:quit` it opens the next file for editing. How to exit vim completely?

I think one solution might be to enter `shell` from vim using `:!bash` and execute `killall vim` but that would kill my other VIM sessions also connected in other terminals. Is there any clean way to do this?

Comment: Unrelated to the answer, but you should avoid `for i in $(any command without consistent output)`. See [this](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) for an explanation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's not Vim, that's Bash. Vim can't stop the subsequent iterations of your Bash loop from spawning a new, unrelated instance of Vim.

Don't do this in a loop. Just invoke a single copy of `vim` and pass it all the files:

```
vim *
```

You can then stop editing at any time with `:qa` or `:quitall`

Comment: In this case, when I quit VIM it says `E173: 14 more files to edit`

Answer (score 2):

Passing all arguments to Vim (as in @meagar's answer) is recommended, and it's bad to parse the output of `ls` for several reasons, but you still can abort the iteration in the `for` loop by checking for Vim's exit status.

```
for i in `ls`; do vim $i || break; done
```

To abort the shell loop, exit the current Vim instance via `:cquit` instead of `:quit`. This will leave Vim with an exit status of 1 instead of 0, and thereby abort the loop.